# Display image in push notification on web using FCM?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated push notification in my project. Here is code from where  I am sending notifications:

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'Access_key' );
        $data = array("to" => 'token',
                      "notification" => array( "title" => 'title', "body" => 'message', "icon" => '/account/images/test.png', "click_action" => 'redirect_url', ));                                                                    
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        $headers = array
        (
             'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY, 
             'Content-Type: application/json'
        );                                                                                 

        $ch = curl_init();  

        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );                                                                  
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );  
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);
```

This code is working properly but here problem is that image is not displaying in notification. I don't why. Where is a problem, how can I display image in notification?

Comment: you are backend developer or android developer

Comment: backend developer

Comment: then don't worry mobile developer can handle this one

Comment: which image you want to display test.png?

Comment: I want to show an image on web also. Image can be of any type. For now i am giving png format

Comment: ok. can you able to receive FCM Data in web like mesg and title etc.

Comment: Yes, all fields are displaying except image.

Comment: try to give full image path

Comment: because  we need to show the image using image original path which means full path e.g(www.yourdomain.com//account/images/test.png)

Comment: @Magnil Amar, I am giving full path and it is correct, I have opened image by writing path in url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake, I am giving icon url as http://www.example.com while icon url always require a secure URL like https://www.example.com. Due to insecure url, it is not showing icon in notifications.

Comment: Can you show how you structured your JSON, plz?